# Permission error when trying to run a mapreduce Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm getting an error when trying to run a Hadoop job. The command that I'm trying to run is the following from /root/folderX:

```
[root@hadoop folderX]# hadoop jar /usr/lib/Hadoop-mapreduce/Hadoop-streaming- 2.2.0.2.0.10.0-1.jar 
-input /user/cxxx/txxx/uxxx.txt 
-output /user/cxxx/txxx/count 
-file map.py 
-file reduce.py 
-mapper map.py 
-combiner reduce.py 
-reducer recude.py
```

I see in a part of the error the following message:

```
Error straming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : Permission denied: user=root, 
access=WRITE, inode=”user”:hdfs:drwxr-wr-x
```

Running the command hadoop fs -ls /user I get the following

```
drwxr-xr-x  - root  hdfs   0 2016-11-01 10:10 /user/cxxx
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /usr/lib/Hadoop-mapreduce/Hadoop-streaming- 2.2.0.2.0.10.0-1.jar 
-input /user/cxxx/txxx/uxxx.txt 
-output /user/cxxx/txxx/count 
-file map.py 
-file reduce.py 
-mapper map.py 
-combiner reduce.py 
-reducer recude.py
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It is confusing as it says 'File file: /root/folderX/map.py does not esixts', but I can definitely see it when I do ls /root/folderX

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem with the following statement:

```
 sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/cxxx
```

I'm not sure how wise is this to do though